# Placing Pandas in a Triangle Pen

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, triangles, pigeonhole-principle

I am working on a bit of a silly problem in my introductory discrete
mathematics course. I have five pandas that I need to place in a pen,
and I have a pen that is the shape of an equilateral triangle with sides
of length 2. I want to prove that If I were to place these five pandas in
the pen, there must be at least two pandas that are of less than or
equal to unit distance from each other. I definitely think this is a
pigeonhole principle problem, although I am not sure what should be
the "boxes'' in this situation. Any assistance would be greatly
appreciated.

Comment: Think about [triforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce).

Comment: Yes, pigeonhole principle is your friend here.  For a more difficult challenge, determine the maximum of minimum distances between pandas (across all possible placements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this diagram, the large triangle has sides of $2$ while the four smaller ones have sides of $1$.

[image]

So place five pandas into those four small triangles. The maximum distance between any two points in any small triangle is clearly just $1$. Use the pigeonhole principle and finish from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can cut the pen into four triangles with side $1$

Answer (score 0):

Connect the mid-points of the sides of the triangle with line segments.This cuts the triangle into 4 pieces. At least 2 of 5 pandas are in the same piece. Each piece is a 1x1x1 equilateral triangle. So two pandas in the same piece cannot be at a distance of more than 1 from each other.